# Manipulating class members with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I want to access and modify members of a class with an `std::thread`.

Here is an example:

```
class bar {
public:
    int a = 5;
    void change_a() {
        a = 10;
        cout << "thread's a=" << a << endl;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    bar object1;

    std::thread t1(&bar::change_a,bar());
    t1.join();

    cout << "object's a=" << object1.a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result was:

> thread's a=10
>
> object's a=5

So the function in the thread modified the variable and printed it, but it obviously did not change the object1 because when I printed that, it was still the same (5).

My question is, where is the variable now 10 if its not an object and how can I work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As threads follow independent code execution.

To Change this you need to pass the address of the object for which you need modification.

```
bar object1;
std::thread t1(&bar::change_a, &object1 );
```

As In C++ , Member functions are called with silent this pointer , which is used for further modification of Objects Contents . Thus here if you pass this correctly you can achieve this.

Know more on [this pointer C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483653/can-you-explain-the-concept-of-the-this-pointer)

Comment: Thank you very much as well, passing a pointer to the object worked!
Just a quick question which is a syntax thing, suppose change_a had an argument:
    void change_a(int x);

and say i wanted to pass it 50, would my line simply look like this?
    std::thread t1(&bar::change_a, 50, &object1);

Answer (score 3):

```
std::thread t1(&bar::change_a, bar());
                               ^^^
```

Here you created a temporary `bar` object. Then, you call `change_a` on this `bar` object, so the `a` is now `10`. Now, when the statement ends, the temporary `bar` object gets destroyed including the variable `a`.

`object1` has nothing to do with that `bar`, it's just another `bar` object, and because you're not calling `change_a` on `object1`, the `a` from `object1` is `5`.

So to answer your question, you are creating 2 objects of type `bar`, but you're only calling `change_a` on one `bar`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation. I understand this now.